# Showing bootstrap spinner while image is loading in iFrame window

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to show "functionality" of the spinner element, to do that I have to find large image and display the spinner while the image loads in iFrame. I tried few things, but nothing seems to work. I also can't find an image large enough to see the effect, I tried using images from effigis.com, but I get `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE`

Html:

```
    <!-- spinner-->
    <h1>4.</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <iframe src="https://effigis.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/DigitalGlobe_WorldView2_50cm_8bit_Pansharpened_RGB_DRA_Rome_Italy_2009DEC10_8bits_sub_r_1.jpg" frameborder="0" width="1000px" height="800px" id="largeimg"></iframe>
        <div class="spinner-border"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

jQuery attempt 1:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // loading icon
            $('#largeimg').imagesLoaded().done(function(){
                $('.spinner-border').remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

jQuery attempt 2:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // loading icon
            $('#largeimg').load(function(){
                $(".spinner-border").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How do I get that spinner after the image loads and how do I even get an image that large to load in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#largeimg').on('load',function(){
        $('.spinner-border').css('display','none');
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/jm8xa6u9/9/)